# Sharepoint 2013 - change dropdown option in Status column based on Expired date (column with formula) Task List

Tags: 2013, calculated-column-formula

Help !!

I have a Status "dropdown selection" Column with the following options

1. Pending Approval
2. Approved
3. In Dispute
4. Re-Assign
5. New Copy
6. Expired

I then have another column "Expired" (Calculated column =[Sent]+28) returning the date 28 days after another column "sent" (Date and Time column format)

What I need help with is :
if the date in "Expired" (calculated column) is reached
then I want the "Status" (dropdown column) to change to Expired on the "Expired" calculated date

Can anyone help please

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, you can utilize a SharePoint Designer workflow:

- Connect to your site using SharePoint Designer.
- Create a new workflow and configure it to trigger on item creation and update.
- Add a "Pause until Date" action and specify the "Expired" calculated date as the wait period.
- Include a "Set Field in Current Item" action to update the "Status" column to "Expired".
- Save and publish the workflow.

Please note that these are general workflow steps, and you may need to adjust the logic based on your specific requirements